# How to configure git mergetool properly for neovim?

Tags: git, git-merge, neovim, mergetool

I'm trying to use neovim as git mergetool but it is not working as expected or as I understood from the documentation.

Here's my `.gitconfig`:

```
[user]
    name = Augusto
[pull]
    rebase = true
[diff]
    tool = nvimdiff
    guitool = nvimdiff
[merge]
    tool = nvimdiff
    conflictstyle = diff3
[mergetool]
    keepBackup = false
    trustExitCode = false
    prompt = true
[difftool]
    prompt = false
[commit]
    gpgsign = true
[core]
    editor = nvim
    pager = bat
[mergetool "nvimdiff"]
    layout = LOCAL,MERGED,REMOTE
```

When I run `git mergetool`, it opens NeoVim as expected, but not with the correct layout. It always opens with the default but not with all the "files" it should open.

Instead of

```
------------------------------------------
|             |           |              |
|   LOCAL     |   BASE    |   REMOTE     |
|             |           |              |
------------------------------------------
|                                        |
|                MERGED                  |
|                                        |
------------------------------------------
```

It is opening like this

```
------------------------------------------
|             |           |              |
|   LOCAL     |   LOCAL   |   MERGED     |
|             |           |              |
------------------------------------------
|                                        |
|                LOCAL                   |
|                                        |
------------------------------------------
```

Command outputs:

```
git config mergetool.nvimdiff.layout
LOCAL,MERGED,REMOTE

git config merge.tool
nvimdiff
```

Comment: A patch for this was just posted to the Git mailing list: https://lore.kernel.org/git/20220708181024.45839-1-greenfoo@u92.eu/

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue where the layout wasn't being applied when using the nvimdiff.  It turns out that you need to use `vimdiff` instead of `nvimdiff` when configuring the layout.  The docs [git-mergetool](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mergetool#Documentation/git-mergetool.txt-mergetoolvimdifflayout) detail that vim and nvim use the same layout config.

```
[mergetool "vimdiff"]
    layout = LOCAL,MERGED,REMOTE
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't really want to use vim. I have many plugins in nvim and using vim I'm losing all of them

Comment: I use nvim as well!  Git shares the above vimdiff config for both vim and nvim.  Did you give it a try and see if it works?

Comment: Yes I have tried. It opens vim instead of neovim.

Comment: What happens when you try `git mergetool --tool nvimdiff`?  If you set your `[merge]
 tool = nvimdiff` in .gitconfig  it shouldn't open vim.

Comment: there is no such thing as `nvimdiff` out of the box

Comment: @FrankovskyiBogdan, the docs would disagree with you https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mergetool#_variants.

Comment: @silentfrost then git docs are incorrect to use it as example, because it's not true. Look at this: https://neovim.io/doc/user/diff.html and you can check it yourself.